# configuring apache sever to access file for php executing

Tags: linux, configuration, lamp, squid

i have installed and configured centos lamp server. And too installed squid proxy server in it.With my php code trying to access squid configuration file located in /etc/squid/squid.conf.But when Apache trying to access squid file it cant. I have given full user permission for squid configuration file.

```
chmod 777 /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

I know am doing something wrong. **I like to know how to configure Apache to access squid configuration file.**

Thanks

Comment: provide php code you are using

Comment: Thanks @ Rahul I have done it atlast

Answer (score 0):

Show me the output `ls -la  /etc/squid/` The problem can be execute (x) permission and you can solved:

`chmod o+x -R /etc/squid`

I hope help you.

Answer (score -1):

disable selinux to solve this problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: i agree with you sorry apologize for posting wrong answer. but now found the correct answer. it is due to file permission problem